# Complex Ef Core Mapping/Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

An ojective should have one Category(one-to-one), 
the objective has Actions and each one of them should have one Action Category(one-to-one) and many Resource Categories(one-to-many).
I don't know how to configure the mapping. Also i'm not sure if my design is correct, how to manage this case properly?

**Summary:**

I need 3 relationships.

1) one-to-one between Objective and Category on ObjectiveCategoryId property of Objective.

2) one-to-one between ObjectiveAction and Category on ActionCategoryId property of ObjectiveAction.

3) one-to-many between ObjectiveAction and Category on ObjectiveId property of Category.

[image]

```
    public class Category {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Objective {
        private ICollection<DevelopmentObjectiveAction> _actions;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int ObjectiveCategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category ObjectiveCategory { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ObjectiveAction> Actions {
            get => _actions ?? (_actions = new List<ObjectiveAction> ());
            set => _actions = value;
        }
    }

    public class ObjectiveAction {
        private ICollection<Category> _resourceCategories;

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public long Objective { get; set; }

        public int ActionCategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category ActionCategory { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Category> ResourceCategories {
            get => _resourceCategories ?? (_resourceCategories = new List<Category> ());
            set => _resourceCategories = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might be helpful if you can diagram out the relationships.

Comment: The description isn't very clear and it seems you are missing one class (Resource). Could you please complete the description of the question and, if possible, add a diagram (as mentioned above)?

Comment: @TonyAbrams  makes sense now?

Comment: @DavidsonSousa  i think my design is wrong, other recommendations are welcome.